# I get error message for basic git commands like 'pwd' & 'cd'

Tags: git, git-bash

My git bash was working fine. But, one day it started showing error messages for everything like 'pwd' command and 'cd' command. This is the error message I'm getting,

git: 'pwd' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: are you sure you aren't executing `git pwd`. Doing that reproduces your error message

Comment: Yes, I'm getting this error message every time when I try to execute 'pwd' command.

paul davis@SONY-VAIO MINGW64 ~
$ git pwd
git: 'pwd' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.

The most similar command is
        add

Comment: yes but why are you running `git pwd` . `pwd` is not a `git` sub command. Try running `pwd` without the `git` preface?

Comment: Yes It's working now. I was being stupid I guess. Thanks though.

Answer (score 2):

PWD is not a git command you should not use it this way `git pwd`

`pwd` is a shell command that returns working directory name.

Comment: Yes, It's working fine when I type just 'pwd' on the interface. i think I messed up. Thanks for your help. Can I ask you one thing ? when I paste something in to git bash (like url or something like that) it's not getting properly pasted. Why it's happening like that? Also, when I try to copy something by ctrl+c it misbehaves.

Comment: @PaulDavis for the copy you can select and use right click and copy OR select and press Ctrl+Shift+C for copy and for paste Ctrl+Shift+P OR right click and paste. if have any other problem please ask with more detail.

Comment: @PaulDavis  if that was the answer for you please vote up and select the correct answer.